# Casting to/creating new System.RuntimeType (for Linq to SQL object)

Tags: c#, linq

I've got a databinding that, when a checkbox is ticked, sets a Linq Object's property, and when unticked, set's it to null.

The problem I'm having is that I'm trying to use a databinding, and the Linq Object's property is a Nullable Type. Here is my method for setting the object:

```
    protected override void OnParse(ConvertEventArgs cevent) {
        if ((Boolean)cevent.Value) {
            cevent.Value = DefaultValue;
        } else {
            cevent.Value = null;
        }
    }
```

For one example, my Linq object property is a DateTime, so my DefaultValue is a DateTime. Except when I reach the point where I'm setting it there's a problem.

It's not expecting a DateTime (found in cevent.DesiredType), it's expecting a RuntimeType (from locals window):

```
    DesiredType {Name = "Nullable`1" FullName = "System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]"}    System.Type {System.RuntimeType}
```

I've tried casting my System.DateTime to this RuntimeType:

```
    cevent.Value = Convert.ChangeType(DefaultValue, cevent.DesiredType);
```

But that's an invalid cast:

An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Invalid cast from 'System.DateTime' to 'System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'.

Anyone have any ideas for a solution? Thanks.

**Edit:**

I've found this to work:

```
    cevent.Value = (System.Nullable<System.DateTime>)DefaultValue;
```

I just need to find a way to do it more generally

**Edit2:**

This doesn't work either, for some reason the OnParse doesn't seem to be actually filtering down and changing the dataMember of the DataSource.

Found out why it doesn't work:

```
    Nullable<float> f = 12;

    f.GetType().Equals(cevent.DesiredType)
```

The Desired Type doesn't equal a Nullable, presumably this is checked somewhere before it attempts to change the property it's bound to.

Comment: What is DesiredType? Where is it declared, what type does it have, where is it set?

Comment: DesiredType is a property of the Binding ConvertEventArgs. It's not created by me, and I'm assuming it's created by the default binding constructor when applying it.

For example, if I bind to a "Checked" on a checkbox, when it gets to "OnFormat" event, the ConvertEventArgs.PreferedType is boolean. When it comes to the "OnParse" event, it's the data type of the property your binding, in this case a Linq object. My problems are where ConvertEventArgs.PreferedType is Nullable<DateTime> and Nullable<float>.

Comment: Apparently, Convert.ChangeType cannot deal with nullables. I don't know if there's anything built in to do this conversion. Maybe you need to detect the nullable case and wrap Convert.ChangeType to layer on additional nullable processing.

Comment: I added an edit to the question, ignoring the dificulty casting to Nullable<whatever>, the DesiredType doesn't even seem to *be* a Nullable<whatever>. It's some kind of other nullable type... :S

Comment: f.GetType() boxes to a float. Nullables are not boxed (special case). f.GetType() == typeof(float). cevent.DesiredType will be equal to typeof(float?). DesiredType refers to a System.Type (base class of RuntimeType) but this Type designates a DateTime?.

Comment: I... I think I fixed it. If I set the 'formatingEnabled' flag on the data binding it seems to manage Nullables fine!